# how to use coalesce mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am trying to update fields but only if the values hold in the sessions are not null. here is my code.

```
 $query='update trac_patientprofiletable
    set name= COALESCE(name,"'.$name.'"),
        date_entered= COALESCE(date_entered,"'.$dateEntered.'"),
        patientdisease= COALESCE(patientdisease,"'.$_SESSION['input']['sPatientDisease'].'"),
        age= COALESCE(age,"'.$_SESSION['input']['sPatientAge'].'"),
        weight= COALESCE(weight,"'.$_SESSION['input']['sPatientWeight'].'"),
        maritalstatus= COALESCE(maritalstatus,"'.$_SESSION['input']['sPatientMaritalStatus'].'"),
        sex= COALESCE(sex,"'.$_SESSION['input']['sPatientSex'].'"),
        levelofeduca= COALESCE(levelofeduca,"'.$_SESSION['input']['sPatientEducationLevel'].'"),
        diagnosis= COALESCE(diagnosis,"'.$_SESSION['input']['sPatientDiagnosis'].'"),
        tbgroup= COALESCE(tbgroup,"'.$_SESSION['input']['sPatientTBgroup'].'"),
        cd4count= COALESCE(cd4count,"'.$_SESSION['input']['sPatientCD4Count'].'"),
        typeofart= COALESCE(typeofart,"'.$_SESSION['input']['sPatientARTRegimen'].'"),
        patientmobileno1= COALESCE(patientmobileno1,"'.$_SESSION['input']['sPatientPhoneNo'].'"),
        language= COALESCE(language,"'.$_SESSION['input']['sPatientCallLanguage'].'"),
        oiprophylaxis= COALESCE(oiprophylaxis,"'.$_SESSION['input']['sPatientOIProhylaxis'].'"),
        eligibleforart= COALESCE(eligibleforart,"'.$_SESSION['input']['sPatientEligibleART'].'"),
        dateartinitiated= COALESCE(dateartinitiated,"'.$_SESSION['input']['sPatientARTDate'].'")
    where patientid="'.$_SESSION['patientid'].'"';        
    $result=mysql_query($query) or die ("query error: ".mysql_error());
```

there is no syntax error .but its not updating the data's in the database. the connection is already established (obviously not shown here). Help please.

Comment: Let's hope that absolutely none of your `SESSION['input']` variables ever will have any SQL injectable characters in them, or you're setting yourself up for quite some debugging.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @h2ooooooo's comment's are especially important, since you are handling patient data. Be extremely aware of your abilities/limitations regarding online security - the legal and psychological damage that can be wrought by leaked medical data is substantial.

Answer (score 2):

Change all your `COALESCE` parameters to be the other way around:

```
oiprophylaxis= COALESCE(oiprophylaxis,"'.$_SESSION['input']['sPatientOIProhylaxis'].'")
```

to

```
oiprophylaxis= COALESCE("'.$_SESSION['input']['sPatientOIProhylaxis'].'",oiprophylaxis)
```

`COALESCE` returns the leftmost non-NULL value, with your current usage it's saying only update `oiprophylaxis` with the new value if `oiprophylaxis` is currently NULL.

What you want is the reverse, only update `oiprophylaxis` with the new value if the new value is not NULL.

Actually this is only part of your problem though, since you're wrapping the values in quotes, and no quoted value is ever going to be NULL. Fortunately that part of your problem will be solved when you take h2ooooooo's advice and use a prepared statement instead.